# font resizing using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, fonts, font-size, html

I have a span with the id of mySpan. I am trying to change the font-size of it via jquery like this:

```
$("#mySpan").css("font-size", "50px");
```

I have also tried this

```
$("#mySpan").css("font-size", 50+"px");
```

But nothing happens, I can change the color of the span like this:

```
$("#mySpan").css("color","#ff0000");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/YdERS/ Is it wrapped with DOM ready handler? jQuery loaded? any errors in console?

Comment: Wrap your code in [DOM Ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) `$(function(){ $("#mySpan").css("color","#ff0000"); })`

Comment: Do "inspect element" and then go through the applied styles.  You should see your new size crossed out and the actual size in a css file or style tag somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is ok, as for the problem, I will go in a wild guess (not so wild actually), that you have another value that overwrites it (for example a class with font-size: xxPx !important), or a child element with font-size defined, etc.

Also Anoop Joshi has a good point. That may be also an issue.

Another possibility would be a broken mark-up (like 2 elements with same id - #mySpan). In this case, the selector would return only the first one, and modify it's font, while leaving the second unchanged.

Comment: +1 but as OP said in question `$("#mySpan").css("color","#ff0000");` works, ready handler is not the issue ;) I guess you are right saying CSS rule is overwritten but other rule

Comment: True, but it may help other ppl that have that issue, so I still see it as a valid point.

Comment: You are correct, better is to be as much as descriptive as possible

Answer (score 2):

Its working fine. Try to give it in document.ready

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#mySpan").css("font-size", "50px");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure the only reason the top one wouldn't work there is because its being overwritten by some other CSS Style..

Try this:

```
 $("#mySpan").css("font-size", "50px !important;");
```

the keyword important will force this to use instead of some other css that is overwriting your change.

**UPDATE:**
Didn't know that (.css doesnt support important) so instead going to put it in a class and add class to myspan:

CSS:

```
.fontSizeFifty
 {  font-size: 50px !important; }
```

JQuery:

```
$('#mySpan').addClass('fontSizeFifty');
```

Comment: no, css() method doesn't support `!important` statement

Comment: Had no idea.. Thanks Wolff

Comment: IMHO, using class should always be the preferred method to set style +1

Answer (score 0):

This should resolve your issue, but I'd much rather have more information and do it in a more correct manner...

```
var mySpan = $("#mySpan")[0]
var style = mySpan.style;
style += (style != "" ? ";" : "") + "font-size:50px !important;";
mySpan.style = style;
```

That will append the new font size directly into the style tag of the selected element, along with `!important`, which should override any styles anywhere else.

This is ugly and I'd never use it myself if there were any other way.  Finding and fixing the originally applied style would be a better way, but if that's not possible then you have this.